# iPhone and Android monthly payment - best ways

Tags: iphone, android, payment-gateway, payment

I have to write monthly payment for these two platforms for one of my clients.

My question is:

1. Can I use PayPal payment for iPhone for this kind of payment? (not buying anything for iTunes, just paying subscribtion).
2. What other payment services providers would you recommend? (for example: In-app purchase for iPhone, something else for Android, etc.)
3. What can you recommend me to use as a library (I saw PayPal X, is this good for example?)

thanks in advance,
Danail

Comment: The question is not right to ask at this place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. We can use Paypal.
2. Other services include:

   - Google Checkout
   - Amazon Payment Services
3. Paypal X is good